# Setting the id column as a PostgreSQL identity field when inserting data into PostGIS with ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr

I want to tell my [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) command which inserts data from a [ESRI Shapefile](https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/sitecore-archive/Files/Pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) into a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)/[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database to create the `id` field as a PostgreSQL [`IDENTITY`](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgresql-10-identity-columns-explained) column (not as a [`SERIAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)).

For the moment, my command:

```sh
$ ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/mydatabase" \
  myshapefile.shp \
  -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom \
  -lco FID=id \
  -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=GIST \
  -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI \
  -nln foo \
  -overwrite
```

creates the table as follow, creating the `id` as a [`SERIAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

```sql
-- Table: public.foo

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.foo;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.foo
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('foo_id_seq'::regclass),
    fid_part numeric(12,0),
    orient numeric(4,0),
    geom geometry(MultiLineStringZ),
    CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.foo
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: foo_geom_geom_idx

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.foo_geom_geom_idx;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS foo_geom_geom_idx
    ON public.foo USING gist
    (geom)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

But if I create the same table using pg:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.foo
(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    fid_part numeric(12,0),
    orient numeric(4,0),
    geom geometry(MultiLineStringZ)
)
```

it creates the table as:

```sql
-- Table: public.foo

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.foo;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.foo
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    fid_part numeric(12,0),
    orient numeric(4,0),
    geom geometry(MultiLineStringZ),
    CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.foo
    OWNER to postgres;
```

How could I achieve the same result with [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create FID as identity with ogr2ogr. In the source code https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/pg/ogrpgdatasource.cpp the alternatives for the datatype of FID are either SERIAL (default) or BIGSERIAL (if layer creation option FID64 is TRUE).

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*      Create a basic table with the FID.  Also include the            */
/*      geometry if this is not a PostGIS enabled table.                */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    const bool bFID64 = CPLFetchBool(papszOptions, "FID64", false);
    const char* pszSerialType = bFID64 ? "BIGSERIAL": "SERIAL";
```

Of course if you only want to create the table with custom parameters it is possible to do with ogrinfo that can execute any SQL.

```sh
ogrinfo PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=my_db user=user password=pw" \
  -sql "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.foo (
          id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
          fid_part numeric(12,0),
          orient numeric(4,0),
          geom geometry(MultiLineStringZ),
          CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
        )
        TABLESPACE pg_default;"
```

Once the table is created it is possible to insert data into now existing table with ogr2ogr by using option `-append`. I made a simple test and it seemed to be successful. New rows were inserted with automatically generated id's.