# How to import GeoPackage with ogr2ogr to existing PostgreSQL table with integer PK?

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr, error, import, geopackage

I'm encountering an error `Null value in column violates not-null constraint` while using the ogr2ogr command to import a GeoPackage into a PostgreSQL table named prj.viewshed_local.

The prj.viewshed_local table has two columns: id_local (integer) and geom (geometry), where id_local is one of the columns in the GeoPackage.

I have observed the following scenarios:

1. When there are no constraints on the prj.viewshed_local table, the ogr2ogr command works fine.
2. When id_local is defined as not null in the prj.viewshed_local table, the ogr2ogr command still works without any issues.
3. However, when id_local is defined as not null and there is a constraint that id_local is the primary key, I encounter an error message stating `"null value in column 'id_local' of relation 'viewshed_local' violates not-null constraint."`

I'm confused because in scenario 2, where the id_local column is defined as not null, the ogr2ogr command executes successfully. Furthermore, I have verified that there are no null values in the id_local column of the GeoPackage's attribute table (and data type is the same: integer).

Here is the ogr2ogr command I'm using:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host={HOST_NAME} port=5432 dbname={DB_NAME} user={USER_NAME} password={USER_PASS}" "{viewshed_dissolved}" -nln {SCHEMA}.{TABLE} -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -append --config PG_USE_COPY YES -makevalid
```

What could be causing this error when the primary key constraint is added? Is there any additional consideration or adjustment I should make to the ogr2ogr command to handle this constraint properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was caused because PK was integer. PK must be **serial**. See [this link](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-December/031099.html) and [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447149/setting-the-id-column-as-a-postgresql-identity-field-when-inserting-data-into-po/447155#447155).